# WebAPI HttpResponse Message

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

For WebAPI2 Action results, HTTPResponseMessage is used as one of the return type and Request.CreateResponse is used to return the message.

Request.CreateResponse is handy when we want to return single instance of the model but if we want to return multiple rows from the “model”, there is no overload method for Request.CreateResponse or Request.CreateResponse which supports it(as far as I read). If someone could post the sample, it would be great

Also, I have few other queries.

•   Why we have to go for HttpResponseMessage rather than IQueryable or Model return type?
•   What is the difference between Request.CreateResponse and Request.CreateResponse , as we are able to return a single instance of the model using both methods. How we can choose one among the two?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the return type of your action method be any serializable data.  Content negotiation and formatters will turn the returned value into an HTTP response for you.

From [Action Results in Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results):

> ### Other Return Types
>
> For all other return types, Web API uses a [media formatter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) to serialize the return value. Web API writes the serialized value into the response body. The response status code is 200 (OK).
>
> ```
> public class ProductsController : ApiController
> {
>     public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
>     {
>         return GetAllProductsFromDB();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> A disadvantage of this approach is that you cannot directly return an error code, such as 404. However, you can throw an `HttpResponseException` for error codes. For more information, see [Exception Handling in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling).
>
> Web API uses the Accept header in the request to choose the formatter. For more information, see [Content Negotiation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation).
>
> Example request:
>
> ```
> GET http://localhost/api/products HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: Fiddler
> Host: localhost:24127
> Accept: application/json
> ```
>
> Example response:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
> Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 08:53:35 GMT
> Content-Length: 56
>
> [{"Id":1,"Name":"Yo-yo","Category":"Toys","Price":6.95}]
> ```

Comment: Thanks Timothy. From an understanding perspective, would like to know. While requesting the response, how we will specify accept only the below types(Through code) Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
And also, would like to know, when we have to specify [FromURI] and [FromBody]..  What will be the URL format while making such request with those attributes.. whats the need to go for [FromURI] and [FromBody]

Comment: For my Original question, i got another response... In order to return multiple records from the model using createResponse<T>, we need to specify createResponse<IEnumerable> or createResponse<IQuerable> or whichever applicable and pass HttpStatusCode and generic parameter